# ASP Style repeater in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to 'loop' through results like the following html is setup with javascript. (Parsing XML in Javascript) But I can't work out how to loop through more than one variable at a time. Basically I keep having the surname loop and loop in one line.

```
 <div class="files-box">
         <img class="replace-2x file-image" width="32" src="images/files/doc.png" alt="img">
             <p class="file-title" id="list">[SURNAME]</p>
             <a href="#" class="file-href file-open">[PHONE NUMBER]</a>
             <a href="#" class="file-href">[CALLLINK]</a>       
             <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>   
     </div>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
function onDeviceReady()
    {

        $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: 'Lookupbysurname.aspx?surname=beech',
               dataType: 'xml',
               success: function(xmlDoc) {
               var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
               $xml.find('Surname').each(function() {
                                           $("#list").append($(this).text());
                                           });
               }
               });

    }

    </script>
```

Basically I'm trying to loop through the xml results (surname, phone number and callink) and re-create the html above each time with the [SURNAME] etc variables replaced by the correct result. It's going in a phonegap app

EDIT: Below as requested is the XML layout

```
<Results>
    <Result>
        <FirstName>Tom</FirstName>
        <Surname>Bedh</Surname>
        <Company>Company INC/Company>
        <Job_Title>Test Title</Job_Title>
        <callID>10582</callID>
        <CompanyID>10001</CompanyID>
    </Result>
</Results>
```

Heres what keeps happening in the current layout

[image]

Comment: Please post a sample XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this. First you need to change your HTML structure:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="files-box">
     <img class="replace-2x file-image" width="32" src="images/files/doc.png" alt="img">
     <p class="file-title surname">[SURNAME]</p>
     <a href="#" class="file-href file-open phone-number">[PHONE NUMBER]</a>
     <a href="#" class="file-href call-link">[CALLLINK]</a>       
     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>   
</div>
​
```

jQuery:

```
var $block = $('#container .files-box').remove();

$xml.find('Result').each(function() {
    var $result = $(this),
        $myblock = $block.clone();

    $myblock.find(".surname").text($result.find('Surname').text());
    $myblock.find(".phone-number").text($result.find('Phone').text());
    $myblock.find(".call-link").text($result.find('callID').text());
    $('#container').append($myblock);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/aKJYZ/

Comment: Thanks for this - but this has the same problem as my code, it has the result in one line and I don't know how to replicate the entire html block with each result

Comment: Updated answer. You should be able to adapt this one to your needs with a little trial and error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I understand the concept but I can't seem to make it actually display any text in the table. Is there a massive difference between the append I had in my code and the text you have in yours?

Comment: Not in this case. Your main problem is that you weren't duplicating the block of HTML, and you had IDs within that block which couldn't be duplicated anyway.